# How to disable attachments button in MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

How to disable this button, I just want people sent normal sms , not attachments.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`disableUserAttachments()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller/1614063-disableuserattachments) before presenting the MFMessageComposeViewController?